# Painting to screen a parameter object's location

Tags: java, swing

We are trying to paint circle objects on different x-y coordinate locations on a background image of a world map.  We have a class called Territory which takes in two integers for x and y coordinates.

```
Territory(String name, int x , int y)...
```

We also have a panel class(extends JPanel) that paints the background image onto the JPanel using an overridden paintComponent method.   However, we cannot figure out a way to pass in the coordinate values and other attributes from another class without breaking the override, or if there is another way to paint on same panel as the background image.

This is our code for the paintComponent method called in the panel class.

```
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  super.paintComponent(g);
         if (image != null)
 g.drawImage(image, 0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this);
```

Answer (score 2):

The custom painting should all be done from within the same paintComponent() method. So basically the panel that paints the background should also have a method like addCircleToPaint(). The circle information should be store in an ArrayList (or something like that). Then in the paintComponent method you paint the image and then loop through the ArrayList and paint the circles.

Or you could use a completely different approach and use [Layered Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html). Use one layer for the background and one layer for the circles.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will produce this image:

[image: Test image]

Note that if you want to draw real territories I would use the [Polygon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) class.

```
public class Test {

    static class Territory {
        String name;
        int x, y;

        public Territory(String name, int x, int y) {
            this.name = name;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawString(name, x, y);
            g.drawOval(x - 50, y - 50, 101, 101);
        }
    }

    static class Map extends JComponent {

     Image bgImage;
        List<Territory> territories;

        public Map(List<Territory> territories) throws Exception {
            this.bgImage = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/Winkel-tripel-projection.jpg/800px-Winkel-tripel-projection.jpg"));
            this.territories = territories;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (Territory territory : territories)
                territory.paint(g);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

        final int w = 800;
        final int h = 400;

        Random r = new Random(8208);
        List<Territory> territories = new LinkedList<Territory>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            territories.add(new Territory("" + i, r.nextInt(w), r.nextInt(h)));

        frame.add(new Map(territories));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(w, h);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```